# GitHub Action: GoReleaser - How to configure it for a library package release?

Tags: go, github-actions, goreleaser

I have several github repositories containing go packages that are libraries rather than binary executables.  How can I configure GoReleaser in my GitHub Actions release script so it generates the release but doesn't try to build and publish binaries?

I found a reference in the documentation, but it was for using goreleaser as a CLI.

Thanks for your help!
Mike

Comment: https://goreleaser.com/cookbooks/release-a-library/

Comment: Unfortunately, nope... As I mentioned in my posting, I am trying to use GoReleaser to build a release in a CICD pipeline with GitHub Actions.  The reference that you mentioned is for using GoReleaser CLI.

Answer (score 1):

add this to your `.goreleaser.yml`:

```yaml
builds:
  - skip: true
```